# Complex Oracle CASE statement needed

Tags: oracle, case-statement

I need to update 20 columns in a given table.   The value I'm going to use depends on a CASE statement.  Currently I have this long statement which looks like this:

UPDATE table X
SET (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5........c20) = (
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN (some condition) THEN 
           ELSE (other value1)
         END,
         CASE
           WHEN (some condition) THEN 
           ELSE (other value2)
         END,
         CASE
           WHEN (some condition) THEN 
           ELSE (other value3)
         END.............

And so on.   All of the WHEN conditions for each column will be the same.   So, is there a way I can code this all in 1 CASE statement something like:

UPDATE table X
SET (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5........c20) = (
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN (some condition) THEN (value1), (value2), (value3),......
           ELSE (value1), (value2), (value3),......
         END...........

Thus eliminating all of the repeated CASE statements?

Or am I stuck with the long version?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on Value1, Value2, ... and ValueN.  If they are all deterministic, then you could code them all in a correlated subquery:

```
create table TableX (
    ID number primary key
  , exp1 number
  , att1 varchar2(30)
  , att2 varchar2(30)
  );

insert into TableX (
  select 1, 1, 'a','b' from dual union all
  select 2, 2, 'a','b' from dual union all
  select 3, 1, 'a','b' from dual union all
  select 4, 2, 'a','b' from dual
);

update TableX
  set (att1, att2) = (
select x.att1, x.att2 
  from (select 1 exp1, 'c' att1,'d' att2 from dual union all
        select 2 exp1, 'x' att1,'y' att2 from dual) x
 where x.exp1 = TableX.exp1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to do this?

```
update tablex
set col1 = val1
     , col2 = val2
     ...
     , col20 = val20
where (some condition)
/

update tablex
set col1 = other1
     , col2 = other2
     ...
     , col20 = other20
where NOT (some condition)
/
```

Obviously, two update statements are more expensive to execute than one. But this implementation is much easier to understand and maintain. So: are you guilty of premature optimization?